# Is there a better way to use SendInput?

Tags: c++

I am using an Xbox controller to send data to my computer, and am using the `SendInput` method to handle keys. I was wondering if there was any other, better way to do this.

```
INPUT Input = { 26 };
Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki.dwFlags = VK_UP;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
std::cout << "Up";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting to direct this to a specific application? It's usually better to send [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

If not, then I would suggest using the [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You can find some good examples on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7305/Keyboard-Events-Simulation-using-keybd_event-funct)